# Calculate the energy gap using Green's function

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, greens-functions, topological-field-theory, topological-insulators

Can I calculate the energy gap of the given Hamiltonian by Green's function?

Is there any basic code in MATLAB to do that?

Comment: What Hamiltonian did you have in mind?

Comment: A Hamiltonian of Topological insulator, i.g., SSH model.

Comment: Yeah, probably. For example, in band theory of insulators, the energy gap is the distance from the top of the filled quasiparticle band to the bottom of the empty band. And those bands are just the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian, which are the poles of the Green's function. So the information is "in there" in a sense... But, I'm not sure exactly how to do it with the Hamiltonian you are interested in.

Comment: I just want to know a formula for this. for example when we calculate the Green' function G=1/(E-H)^-1 we can use the trace of Green's function to determine the density of state.

Comment: Plot the density of states and look for a gap.